# Adding and removing class multiple times when scroll the page - wrong behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

When `<div>` goes to the top, this `<div>` add the class "*is-active*" but, for some reason sometimes the `<div>` add and remove the class repeatedly

You can see this behaviour on this gif [on this gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/S7JqZ1bLQdKHmL5jlz/giphy.gif)!

jQuery:

```
       banner = $('.travel__banner')

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

            banner.each(function(){
                var bannerTop = $(this).offset().top
                if ( scrollTop >= bannerTop ) {
                    $(this).addClass('is-active');
                    banner.not($(this)).removeClass('is-active')
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('is-active');
                }
            });
        });
```

Html:

```
<div class="travel">
        <div class="travel__banner">
            <div class="travel__banner__crop">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//marbela.jpg" alt="xirau">
                <h2 class="travel__banner__date"> 10/04 </h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="travel__content">
            <span class="travel__content__hour"> 12:00 </span>
            <h2 class="travel__content__title"> Road Bike na costa brava </h2>

            <img class="travel__content__image" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//marbela.jpg"
                alt="xirau">

            <p class="travel__content__text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula
                ligula consectetur lorem porta, at tristique justo tempor. Vivamus eu eros eget nunc </p>
        </div>

        <div class="travel__content">
            <span class="travel__content__hour"> 12:00 </span>
            <h2 class="travel__content__title"> Road Bike na costa brava </h2>

            <img class="travel__content__image" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//marbela.jpg"
                alt="xirau">

            <p class="travel__content__text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula
                ligula consectetur lorem porta, at tristique justo tempor. Vivamus eu eros eget nunc </p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="travel">
        <div class="travel__banner">
            <div class="travel__banner__crop">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//bike-2.jpg" alt="xirau">
            </div>
            <h2 class="travel__banner__date"> 11/04 </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="travel__content">
            <span class="travel__content__hour"> 12:00 </span>
            <h2 class="travel__content__title"> Road Bike na costa brava </h2>

            <img class="travel__content__image" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//bike-2.jpg"
                alt="xirau">

            <p class="travel__content__text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula
                ligula consectetur lorem porta, at
                tristique justo tempor. Vivamus eu eros eget nunc </p>
        </div>

        <div class="travel__content">
            <span class="travel__content__hour"> 12:00 </span>
            <h2 class="travel__content__title"> Road Bike na costa brava </h2>

            <img class="travel__content__image" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/img//bike-2.jpg"
                alt="xirau">

            <p class="travel__content__text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula
                ligula consectetur lorem porta, at
                tristique justo tempor. Vivamus eu eros eget nunc </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I expect that when the `<div>` goes to the top does not have this bug adding and removing class, just add one single time

Comment: gif URL is broken

Comment: @DaryllChandler now It's ok

Comment: Do you want to remove `is-active` class from the first element when the next element reach top or just add another class?